# OS X productivity application to block access to different websites?

Tags: parental-controls, productivity

I am looking for an OS X application that would **block you from accessing certain websites, like social and entertainment one** and even hide applications.

The entire purpose is to **create a working environment that allows you to focus on your job**.

I have to mention that, the web-browser cannot be banned because it is required to normal use.

Also, the solution I am looking for should provide a way to harden the switching from no-distration mode to unlocked.

This question is about a software solution, so please refrain from recommending books to read regarding productivity.

I realise that using **Parental Control** and having a managed account would solve some of these but there are some essential problems:

- Applications are not hidden, the system just asks for admin password, yuck.
- You have to create the list of denied websites yourself, that makes it impossible to manager. Is there a predefined list that we can import?
- How to share the documents I'm working on between the two accounts: normal one and restricted one.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Antisocial](http://anti-social.cc/) for this:

> Anti-Social is a productivity application for Macs that turns off the social parts of the internet. When Anti-Social is running, you’re locked away from distracting social media sites, including Facebook, Twitter and other sites you specify. With Anti-Social, you’ll be amazed how much you get done when you turn off your friends.

But of course this works only for web sites, not for local applications.